# How to change redirected local address of password reset request in Laravel5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to add password reset function to my application in Laravel5.4 and the application is able to send an email to the specific address now. But, when I click on the [reset my password] button in the email, it redirects me to /localhost/ Such as http://localhost/password/reset/, however, my localhost address is 127.0.0.1:8000. In this case, I need to change [localhost] part to [127.0.0.1:8000].

I tried to search app.url in my application, changed all related addresses and keys to 127.0.0.1:8000 and nothing helped.

I have this code in my ResetPassword.php for my button:

```
 ->action('Reset Password', url(config('app.url').route('password.reset', $this->token, false)))
```

So how can I change localhost to any other addresses? Such as 127.0.0.1:8000 in my case.

Comment: Whats the value in APP_URL in .env ?

Comment: @PetyoTsonev I found the error at app.php but the value of APP_RUL in .env was 127.0.0.1:8000. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`config('app.url')` is the url configured in your `config/app.php`. It is usually read from the APP_URL environment variable in your .env file.

Ref: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/app.php#L55